# Mysql add string to multiple-columns

Tags: mysql, string, addition, multiple-columns

I have a database of some products. A column is name of products. In this column i want to add a word in some of them which include specific word. Let me give an example:

1 column  new pillow 2 column new carpet, I want to add the word case only after the word pillow like this 
new pillow case and the 2. column  new carpet must be stay same new carpet

Comment: Use `WHERE column LIKE '%pillow%'` to find the rows with `pillow` in the column.

Comment: consider structuring your data

Comment: Please explain your question, or write in proper structure. Not able to understand what you r trying to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MySQL `REPLACE()` replaces all the occurrences of a substring within a string.

```
Replace(column,'pillow','pillow case')
```

demo query :-

```
Select Replace(column,'pillow','pillow case') column
From table
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE(`name`,'Cushion','Cushion Cover')
FROM fac_urun LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(name,'Cushion','Cushion Cover') FROM fac_urun LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: please try this query @FatihArslan

Comment: $cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique']¶
Type: boolean
Default value: false
Defines whether to show row links (Edit, Copy, Delete) and checkboxes for multiple row operations even when the selection does not have a unique key. Using row actions in the absence of a unique key may result in different/more rows being affected since there is no guaranteed way to select the exact row(s).

Comment: i am not understand your problem but this query working fine  please check this link :(  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/33799 @FatihArslan